# How to count object which not in main method in java?

Tags: java

I've tried to count the object that I already created from another class using static variable which I placed it inside the constructor, so it can grow every time the object is created.

My question is how to count the object when the object is not in main and then call the static variable in main method so it shows the value?

Can you tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
public class MataKuliah {
public static int JumlahMataKuliah = 0;

private String kode, Nama;

private int SKS;

public MataKuliah(String kode, String Nama, int SKS) {
    this.kode = kode;
    this.Nama = Nama;
    this.SKS = SKS;
    JumlahMataKuliah++;

}
}

public class Ruang {
public static int JumlahRuang = 0;

private  String Nama, Gedung;
private int Kapasitas;

MataKuliah prolan = new MataKuliah("123GTW", "Pemrograman Lanjut", 5);  
MataKuliah sisdig = new MataKuliah("121FGH", "Sistem Digital", 3);
MataKuliah agama = new MataKuliah("009JSH", "Agama", 2);
MataKuliah bind = new MataKuliah("165BGS", "Bahasa Indonesia", 2);
MataKuliah database = new MataKuliah("887BVC", "Database", 4);



public Ruang(String Nama, String Gedung, int Kapasitas) {
    this.Nama = Nama;
    this.Gedung = Gedung;
    this.Kapasitas = Kapasitas;
    JumlahRuang++;


}
}

public class Mahasiswa {
public static int JumlahMahasiswa = 0;

private String Nama, NIM;


Ruang R1 = new Ruang("E2.1", "E", 40);
Ruang R2 = new Ruang("E2.2", "E", 35);
Ruang R3 = new Ruang("A1.5", "A", 38);
Ruang R4 = new Ruang("C2.0", "C", 40);

 public Mahasiswa(String Nama, String NIM) {
    this.Nama = Nama;
    this.NIM = NIM;
    JumlahMahasiswa++;

}

}

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Mahasiswa mhs1 = new Mahasiswa ("Paijo","627362362823");


    System.out.println("\n\njumlah matkul : "+MataKuliah.JumlahMataKuliah);
    System.out.println("jumlah ruang : "+Ruang.JumlahRuang);
    System.out.println("Jumlah Mahasiswa : "+Mahasiswa.JumlahMahasiswa);
}

}
```

and it shows that I have value 20 in my `JumlahMataKuliah` static variable.
How to count it properly so it shows only five, since I only created 5 objects?

Comment: You create 1 `Mahasiswa` which creates 4 `Ruang`. Each `Ruang` creates 5 `MataKuliah`. 1x4x5 = 20.

Answer (score 0):

Each Mahasiswa creates 4 Ruang Objects which then create 5 MataKuliah, which means your MataKuliah.JumlahMataKuliah is 4x5=20. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are shared between all instances, meaning you can say Class.variable to acces the variable from a main method

```
public class SomeClass{
    public static int instances = 0;
    public SomeClass(){
        this.instances++;
    }
}

public class TestClass(){
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Sysrem.out.println(SomeClass.instances);
    }
}
```

note that using this meand that EVERY instance of the class counts the amount of class instances created as +1(since it's a constructor call), so if you are creating a class using another class then if more than 1 is created, then more than 1 is added to instace count

As mentioned in the comment, you get this issue because you are creating multiple instances of another class in a class and expecting both to be the same amount of instances